# Analyze ~10 million row dataset (2.12 GB) in R

Tags: database, r, odbc, bigdata

I've done a bit of searching, but nothing I've found satisfies my question too well...

I have a table in my Oracle database which I would like to run regression on, make classification/regression trees on, etc, in R. The table itself is almost 10 million rows - 2.12GB in a .tsv file -  with 28 fields of varying types (integer, numeric, varchar, timestamp, etc), and I have 'exported' it to a .tsv file.

I need to know how to import this data to R, and if R can even "handle" data of this size. I have researched the RODBC package and attempted to use odbcConnect, but I have no clue what the 'dsn' parameter is of that command. Is this a combination of my database's SID + hostname? Even if I knew the dsn parameter and connect my database to R, would I be able to get the table into a data.frame and perform general analysis on it?

Both general and specific responses would be warmly appreciated!

Thanks,
Clark

Comment: The limit to what you can read into R is the amount of RAM you have.

Comment: The short response is Yes, R can handle a 2.12GB file.  The more detailed response is that whether R can handle it on **your machine** is dependent on a few things.  One of the most important is the amount of RAM you have in your machine, and how much of it you have made available for R to use.  If you use R alone to run a script on this file, be prepared to wait.  A much faster way is to read it into a shell and cut it up into chunks of only the data you intend to use, then send that to R.

Comment: The RODBC package's [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf) goes into _incredible_ detail on how to set up DSNs on multiple platforms.

Comment: Scratch what I said.  It doesn't apply to databases.  Go with @joran 's suggestion.  You can read in directly from the web.

Comment: If you have the data as a delimited text file then `fread` will be the fastest avenue to loading into R. With regards memory, you'll need to be on 64-bit Windows to make use of your RAM in full.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df <- read.table('file.tsv', header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

R should be able to handle data sets that large. You can always split it up into smaller files using a split utility.

Comment: Unfortunately, I encounter a "fatal error" when I try doing so. I only have 4gb of RAM on my computer, which I think is the cause. I have since solved this problem by sampling my data...